# Set initial value for dynamically created ModelChoiceField in Class Based View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm creating a `Form` which has a `ModelChoiceField`. I'm able to set the values for this field as follows:

```
class DeviceForm(Form):
    devices = ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=RadioSelect, empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user_id = kwargs['initial']['user_id']
        devices = Device.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, is_validated=True)
        self.fields['devices'].queryset = devices
```

This works perfectly, but I can't seem to be able to set an initial value. I've tried multiple things such as adding an initial value to `get_initial()`:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(DeviceView, self).get_initial()
    initial['user_id'] = self.kwargs['user_id']
    default_device = Device.objects.get(user_id=self.kwargs['user_id'], is_validated=True, is_default=True)
    initial['devices'] = default_device.id
    return initial
```

But that doesn't work. I've come across multiple questions on StackOverflow which instantiate the form and pass in an initial value like so:

```
#Get default device
form = DeviceForm(initial={'devices': default_device.id})
```

But ideally I would like to avoid it, since I'm trying to stick to the Django generic base views (which look like this, and don't allow for an `initial` kwarg as far as I'm aware):

```
def get(self, request, user_id, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff

    form = self.get_form()
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Setting devices in `get_initial()` should work, since the `self.get_form_kwargs()` returns:

```
{'prefix': None, 'initial': {'user_id': u'1', 'devices': 42}}
```

or, depending on what I'm supposed to choose:

```
{'prefix': None, 'initial': {'user_id': u'1', 'devices': <Device: Device object>}}
```

Doing the following still doesn't get it to work (basically the the same thing as `get_form()` manually).

```
def get(self, request, user_id, **kwargs):
    #Do stuff
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Setting the initial value in the constructor of the Form also doesn't work:

```
class DeviceForm(Form):
    devices = ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=RadioSelect, empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user_id = kwargs['initial']['user_id']
        devices = Device.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, is_validated=True)
        self.fields['devices'].queryset = devices
        default_device = devices.filter(is_default=True)
        self.fields['devices'].initial = default_device  # or default_device.id
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a dumb mistake on my part in the template. The value actually got set correctly in the view, but I forgot to set the `checked` value in the template. I thought it was just using `{{form}}`, but I wasn't. Just for people who are wondering how you can set it manually:

```
{% for device in form.devices.field.choices.queryset %}
    <input type="radio" name="devices" value="{{ device.pk }}" class="radio-device"
        {% ifequal form.devices.value device.pk %}checked{% endifequal %}
    />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the suggested way to assign `initial`, but it's still available in class based views. Quoting from [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views):

```
class MyFormView(View):
    form_class = MyForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'form_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: This basically gets done in the `get()` using the methods provided by Django. `self.get_form_kwargs()` contains `'initial': {'devices': 42}`, but it's still not getting set with either id or object (what does it need to be?). Care to take a look at my updated question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already overridden your form's `__init__` method, it might be easiest to set the initial value there.

```
class DeviceForm(Form):
    devices = ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=RadioSelect, empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user_id = kwargs['initial']['user_id']
        devices = Device.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, is_validated=True)
        self.fields['devices'].queryset = devices
        default_device = Device.objects.get(user_id=user_id, is_validated=True, is_default=True)
        self.fields['devices'].initial = default_device
```

Comment: I didn't mentioned it, but I tried this same exact thing. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Neither with the `default_device` not the `default_device.id` (which I believe should be correct).